# How to convert duration format ( dd HH mm ) to linera minutes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, format, duration

my goal is to display a circular progress bar in function of different duration. To simplify my calculation I search to convert duration, for example I have 00days 02hours 30minutes I want 150min

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with **abs** method. e.g.

```
var d = Duration(hours: 2,minutes: 30);
print(d.abs().inMinutes); // 150
```

Hope this help.